# Why is Wordpress/Apache returning a 503 error?

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, 503-error

I have two separate WordPress nodes running with an Haproxy load balancer out front. After I got my infrastructure set up, tested, and working, a few hours later the whole infrastructure is down and all that I get is a 503. Of course, initially I assumed excess traffic, but after I restarted each WordPress node, I realized a problem. On any of my WordPress nodes, if I run

```
wget http://127.0.0.1:80 -O -
```

the result is

```
--2017-04-07 04:17:34--  http://127.0.0.1/
Connecting to 127.0.0.1:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

and after about 4 seconds, it returns with

```
503 Service Unavailable
2017-04-07 04:17:36 ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.
```

Obviously, a 4 second response time localhost is a dead giveaway something is wrong with the server. However, the CPU and RAM usage is normal, running `sudo apache2ctl status` yields the correct results, apache2 config files are good, so on.

I'm bewildered that this was working earlier and suddenly the whole infrastructure breaks. I can't think of anything that would have caused a change that would cause this kind of behavior. Apache error log file for one of the nodes is attached below, although nothing looks out of place, only the manual restarts I did. Thoughts?

```
[Thu Apr 06 21:27:19.583583 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 1694] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Apr 06 21:27:20.603065 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8384] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 06 21:27:20.603220 2017] [core:notice] [pid 8384] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Apr 06 22:03:45.892434 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 8384] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Thu Apr 06 22:03:47.070402 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9535] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Apr 06 22:03:47.070532 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9535] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Apr 07 03:09:33.930486 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9535] AH00173: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Fri Apr 07 03:09:34.055213 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9535] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 07 03:09:34.055362 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9535] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Apr 07 03:49:01.465024 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9535] AH00173: SIGHUP received.  Attempting to restart
[Fri Apr 07 03:49:01.577496 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9535] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 07 03:49:01.577628 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9535] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Apr 07 04:06:50.129119 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9535] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Fri Apr 07 04:06:50.255452 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9535] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Apr 07 04:06:50.255480 2017] [core:notice] [pid 9535] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: What is in PHP error logs?

Comment: My first thought was PHP as well. When you edit your question to add the PHP logs please add the output of top or atop as well.